# Action Cable is not working with rails 5

Tags: ruby, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am a beginner in Rails 5 and I am trying to implement web sockets in my app. I am trying to copy and run a test app at first and I figure out it is not working as it is not transmitting and receiving the data. `received: (data) ->` is never called. I also observed that it never gets connected with my redis server either (which I installed with brew). I am pasting all the code below. Thanks in advance.

```
//room.coffee

App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create "RoomChannel",
connected: -> 
# Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server 
disconnected: -> 
# Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server 

received: (data) -> 
alert(data['message'])
speak: (message) -> 
@perform 'speak', message: message
```

room_chanel.rb

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file. Action 
Cable runs in a loop that does not support auto reloading.
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
def subscribed
 stream_from "room_channel"
end

def unsubscribed
  # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
end

def speak(data)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel", message: data['message']
end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'redis'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.x'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

cable.yml

```
# Action Cable uses Redis by default to administer connections, channels, and sending/receiving messages over the WebSocket.
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

cable.coffee

```
# Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
    # You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the rails generate channel command.
    #
    # Turn on the cable connection by removing the comments after the require statements (and ensure it's also on in config/routes.rb).
    #
    #= require action_cable
    #= require_self
    #= require_tree ./channels
    #
    @App ||= {}
    App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer()
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use Action Cable without Redis (since Redis is not strictly required for Action Cable):

```
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

But this probably is not the origin of your problem. Your `room.coffee` lacks some `speak`-calling code. Add to `room.coffee` something like this:

```
$ ->
  $('#send_form').submit (event)->
    App.room.speak event.currentTarget['message'].value
    event.currentTarget['message'].value = ""
    event.preventDefault()
    false
```

Here's a template:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <form id="send_form">
    <label>Message:</label>
    <input id="message" type="text" data-behavior="room_speaker">
    <br> 
    <input type="submit" data-behavior="room_speaker">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to set `gem 'pg'` instead of `gem 'sqlite3'` (and bundle install) 

See also:

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/creating-a-chat-using-rails-action-cable

Comment: I will try that, but what is the reason of setting 'pg' instead of 'sqlite3'

Comment: 1 https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/creating-a-chat-using-rails-action-cable#installing-actioncable
2 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#dependencies